# Warning message on a successful action

Tags: gui-design, guidelines, error-message, warnings

In the web application that we are building, there is a process where the user uploads a file. This file will be uploaded even if there are warnings because the warnings are solved by the application itself. The file won't be uploaded when there are errors.

I am trying to find what would be the best way to present that:

> The process is successful, but there are warnings detected

So far I have come up with these solutions, but I am open to new suggestions. Is there any Guidelines about this issue?

[image: Possible solutions]

Comment: Is there anything to be done (should be done?) about the warnings or the user can ignore them?

Comment: They can see the warnings and what has been done to solve them. Most likely the user will ignore them

Comment: If user ignores the warnings, are they saved anywhere or just vanish? What if currently there is no time to review and she wants to postpone warnings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The process is successful, but there are warnings detected

What you have is Notice1 + Notice2 + Action.

**Product upload successful + There were warnings + View warnings**

The examples you propose combine these points, but in my opinion you need at least two different elements, which are examples 3 and 4. From these, 3 can cause some confusion as the first message says "Success, everything went correctly" but the second "349 things went wrong". 4 on the other hand tells "Success, although some things didn't go correctly" and then you give a button to view what went wrong.

So I think 4 is the best of your options. About the style the only problem I can see is that you are using a similar style for the notice and the button, which might make the notice look like a button or the button not look like one.

---

About this last point, these are some proposals just to illustrate. **Depending on the importance of these warnings** you might want to make the View action more or less prominent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I see your point! How would you change the style? Could you demonstrate?

Comment: Sure! I'll update with some proposals :)

Comment: Super! Thanks! I really like the second approach, because in the first one the warning are too prominent

Comment: Remember not to abuse the warning indicator if the user is likely to ignore the warnings. On the other hand - from your example and the number of warnings I assume the chance of warning-free product upload is almost zero. In such case you can show the user a link to "upload report" or "non-fatal issues".

Comment: @Mike a "send report" is a good idea. Possibly from the warnings window or dialog I think.

Comment: I would go with #1 because at least your eye is drawn to the yellow. If you have all green, people will skip it because they will *assume* that nothing went wrong.

Answer (score 10):

> This file will be uploaded even if there are warnings because the
>   warnings are solved by the application itself.

By referring to your sentence above, **would it be worth allocating that much of space and users attention to something that a system can solve itself**?

Update: Want to shift this @[Mike](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/98561/mike)'s comment in answer -

## "See 349 warnings fixed automatically"

---

Here are some patterns in use that will help you style your elements properly:

## MS Outlook:

[image]

---

## Octopus

[image]

---

## Mailchimp

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dipak for your answer. As for your question: It is quite important for the user to know what alterations the system has made. It is an important user requirement for our clients

Comment: "See 345 issues fixed automatically" message would be the most appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: @DimitraMiha just to clarify - if the system is solving the warnings, will the action button help users in any way?

Comment: @Mike Totally agree!

Comment: @Mike Agree as well! Dipak Very good question: The user can change still change things manually after the file is uploaded. The file contains some information that is added to the system. Maybe an appropriate action would be to see what they uploaded which has warnings. I will keep this remark in my design! Thanks

Comment: Your answer has a lot of valid points. I am accepting @Mike answer's mainly because he designed his thoughts. Thank you again for your contribution!

Answer (score 2):

User should see warnings before the success message

First notification should be in orange: 349 warnings were detected
and the second one (after some time, letting user to read first notification) should be in green saying 'Product upload is successful!'

Comment: So you would expect something the 3 representation, but reversed?

Comment: Hm... I tend to shy away from time-delayed messages when they aren't necessary. If the system already uploaded successfully and fixed warnings, you should alert the user immediately on reception of both pieces, otherwise you run the risk of a fast user reading "warnings" and clicking to take action before the success message comes up. I could understand if there was some asynchronous action happening (Client side validated that there were 200 warnings>display, then server responds after that the file was successfully uploaded), but if it all comes in at once don't delay data from the user.

Comment: Yes but they should share same field. When warning fades away, success message will be visible. From my understanding of your situation, you don't need to show these warnings' definitions to users, because system handles them. If not, you need a link to these warnings. For this situation, you should show a success notification and it includes 'see warnings' inline text at the end of it.